# Split by special criterion (perl)

Tags: perl

I have a line which contains one, two or three words that start with LowerCase followed by a colon and each followed by a few (arbitrary) words that start with UpperCase:

example (arbitrary):

```
alpha: Beta beta gamma: Alpha Beta gamma beta gamma: Omega Omega omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi
```

split criterion: any number of words that start with lowercase follow by colon.

example:

```
alpha: Beta
beta gamma: Alpha Beta
gamma beta gamma: Omega Omega
omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi
```

a little help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The algorithm seems simple: advnce to next `:`, then split at `space followed by lowercase letter`.

Comment: Do you plan on further processing these words? It seems like it might be easier/more useful to split it into a list like `("alpha", ":", "Beta", "beta", "gamma", ":", "Alpha", "Beta", ...)`, from which point you might be able to work with it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lcword  = qr!\b[a-z]+!;      # all-lowercase word
my $ucfword = qr!\b[A-Z][a-z]+!; # word with a leading uppercase letter
my @list = $string =~ m!((?:$lcword|\s)+: (?:$ucfword|\s)+)!g;
print join("\n", @list), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a substitution rather than a split.

```
$string =~ s/(stuff that must precede a newline)(stuff that must follow a newline)/\1\n\2/g;
```

The g at the end makes it global. The first paren should probably match any number of words beginning with an uppercase, and the second should match any number of lowercase words followed by a colon (or semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the semicolon (did you mean colon?) doesn't seem to be load-bearing.  Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {       # for each line, look for
  s! \b([A-Z][a-z]+)   #  - a capitalized word
       \s+             #  - followed by whitespace
     ([a-z]+)          #  - followed by a lowercased word
   !$1\n$2!xg;         # and turn that whitespace into a newline
  print;
}

__END__
alpha: Beta beta gamma: Alpha Beta gamma beta gamma: Omega Omega omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi
```

This prints:

```
alpha: Beta
beta gamma: Alpha Beta
gamma beta gamma: Omega Omega
omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off with split, but if you want to do it with a regexp:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $string = "alpha: Beta beta gamma: Alpha Beta gamma beta gamma: Omega Omega omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi";

my @list = $string =~ /(\b[a-z]\w+(?: [a-z]\w+){0,2}: [A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+)*)/g;

print "$_\n" for @list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $string="alpha: Beta beta gamma: Alpha Beta gamma beta gamma: "
    ."Omega Omega omega alpha: Gamma Omega Phi";
my @list = split /\s([^A-Z]+|\s+)\:\s+/, $string;
my @first = split /\:/, $list[0];
shift @list;
@list = (@first,@list);
print $string.$/;
print $_,$/ for @list;
```