# How can I split a line of text using Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [join lines after colon (perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265265/join-lines-after-colon-perl)

There may be the next line like this :

```
red: alpha green: beta, gamma blue: alpha, beta yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)
```

This line can contain more characters such as any of these:

```
xxx: yyyy
xxx: yyyy, zzzz
xxx: yyyy (zzz) yyyyy (xx)
```

I want to split this line according to the following criteria:

The part of input which reads "yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)" is being distributed as "yellow: alpha (gamma)", "yellow: beta (alpha)", "yellow: gamma (beta)".

Find "word followed by colon" and add this as indent of new line, generating one line if "word followed by colon" is followed by one word that does not contain acolon, two lines if "word followed by colon" is followed by two (possibly comma-separated) words that do not contain a colon.  If the second word after "word followed by a colon" is parenthesized, then the parenthesized information belong on a line with the word preceding it.

#### Example 1:

line

```
aa: bb ccc
```

split

```
aa: bb
aa: ccc
```

#### Example 2:

line

```
aa: bb, ccc ddd: aa eee ff
```

split

```
aa: bb
aa: ccc
ddd: aa
ddd: eee
ddd: aa
```

#### Original

For the original example input, the output should be:

```
red: alpha
green: beta
green: gamma
blue: alpha
blue: beta
yellow: alpha (gamma)
yellow: beta (alpha)
yellow: gamma (beta)
```

Comment: That's example output, not criteria. What are the criteria?

Comment: So not merely splitting, but also distribution. The part of your input which reads "yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)" is being distributed as "yellow: alpha (gamma)", "yellow: beta (alpha)", "yellow: gamma (beta)". Correct?

Comment: Is it ever possible for some data on the right-hand side of the split to contain a colon? eg: `xxx: yyy:zzz` or similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265265/join-lines-after-colon-perl

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924247/split-by-special-criterion-perl

Hmmm.

Comment: I think there are far too many `split` questions with the same generic titles. This may or may not explain the large spate of `split` questions recently, even though the principles behind the answer are more or less the same as what is already present on SO today

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = 'red: alpha green: beta, gamma blue: alpha, beta yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)';
my @tmp = split /\s*?(\w+):\s*/, $line;
shift @tmp;
while (my ($color, $value) = splice @tmp, 0, 2) {
    foreach my $v (split /, | (?!\()/, $value) {
        print "$color: $v\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @toplevels;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    @toplevels = split /(?=\w+:)/;
}
for my $chunk (@toplevels) {
    my ($color, $line) = ( $chunk =~ /(^\w+:)(.+)/ );
    my @line = split /[,)]/, $line;
    for (@line) {
        printf "%s%s%s\n", $color, $_, m/\(/ ? ')' : '';
    }
}
__DATA__
red: alpha green: beta, gamma blue: alpha, beta yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

while (<DATA>) {
    for my $unit (/[a-z]+:\s*[a-z, ()]+\s+(?=[a-z]+:)?/g) {
        if ($unit =~ /^([a-z]+:)\s*(.+)$/) {
            my $key = $1;
            my @val = split /[, ]+(?!\()/, $2;
            say "$key $_" for @val;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
red: alpha green: beta, gamma blue: alpha, beta yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "red: alpha green: beta, gamma blue: alpha, beta yellow: alpha (gamma) beta (alpha) gamma (beta)";

for my $key_values (split/(?=\w+:)/, $string) {
    my ($key, $values) = split/: /, $key_values;
    for my $value (split/, |(?<=\)) | (?!\()/, $values) {
        print "$key: $value\n";
    }
}
```

Golfed version:

```
map{s/(.+: )//;map{print"$1$_\n"}split/, |(?<=\)) | (?!\()/}split/(?=\w+:)/,$string;
```

**EDIT:** I overlooked one of the "requirements" so I had to update the third regex.